# html css or php gd library two image merge corner to corner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

http://imageshack.com/a/img560/3302/jojv.jpg

İ have a question for designers! I wanna make index design. i try css divs and php gd library. My css and html.

```
    .arrow-left {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(./filmback.jpg);
    width: 0; 
    /* height: 0; */ 
    border-top: 60px solid rgba(173, 10, 10, 1);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-style: solid;
    /* border-left-color: green; */
    z-index: 1;
}
.arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(./back.jpg);
    width: 0; 
    /* height: 0; */ 
    border-top: 60px solid rgba(173, 10, 10, 1);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-style: solid;
    /* border-left-color: green; */
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and html

```
<html style="height:100%; margin:0px;">
<head>      
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/720p.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var halfWidth = ($('body').width());
        var halfheight = ($('body').height());
        $('#div2').css('border-top-width', '0px');
        $('#div2').css('border-left-width', halfWidth + 'px');
        $('#div2').css('border-bottom-width', halfheight + 'px');
        $('#div2').css('border-right-width', halfWidth + 'px');
        $('#div1').css('border-bottom-width', '0px');
        $('#div1').css('border-right-width', halfWidth + 'px');
        $('#div1').css('border-top-width', halfheight + 'px');
        $('#div1').css('border-left-width', halfWidth + 'px');
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="height:100%; margin:0px;">
<div class="arrow-right" id="div2"></div>
<div class="arrow-left" id="div1" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

first and second div look perfect. But `div2` on `div1` and `div2` background not show. i try php gd  too but i dont it because gd is need perfect math! My math is sucks. How can i this? i think make this very simple but if u dont know how this is very hard! Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some basic HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a {
    border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
    border-color: #f00 transparent transparent transparent;
}
#b {
    border-width: 0 0 200px 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #00f transparent;
}
#a, #b {
    position:absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/W4E4t/)**

Comment: Thanks for help. I made this. But i dont use solid color. i need this with use 2 image. Not solid color. Two different images.